# How to get exitcode from XML file using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, exit-code

I have a XML file look like this:

```xml
<Feature>
    <B7>A</B7>
    <B8>B</B8>
    <B9>C</B9>
    <ExitCode>
        <Found>123</Found>
        <NotFound>789</NotFound>
    </ExitCode>
</Feature>
```

I have a PowerShell script look like this:

```bsh
$regex = [regex]$Pattern
$matching = $regex.Match($FB)
if ($matching.Success) {
    while ($matching.Success) {
        "Match found: {0}" -f $matching.Value
        exit 123 #I want to delete this
        $matching = $matching.NextMatch()
    }
} else {
    "Not Found" 
    exit 789 #I want to delete this
}
```

I want to get the exitcode, but I don't want to write `exit 123` and `exit 780`, I just want to call the exit code from XML file, so everytime I want to change the exitcode number, I just modify from XML file, not from the PowerShell script.

So, I can get the exitcode log if I run the script using batch file, look like this:

```batch
set log=C:\Users\Log.txt
set PS=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
set PS=%PS%\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 

"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\XML.ps1 -i C:\Users\Feature.txt -j C:\Users\XML.xml

echo %ERRORLEVEL% > "%log%"
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where the XML comes into play in your PowerShell code. You neither read nor process it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get powershell to return the correct exit code when called with the -File argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620507/how-can-i-get-powershell-to-return-the-correct-exit-code-when-called-with-the-f). Your question definitely does **NOT** present a [mcve] (even after reading through your previous questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this; read the XML file, then get the numbers from it by property references:

```
$xmlData = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlData.Load('c:\test\data.xml')

$regex = [regex]$Pattern
$matching = $regex.Match($FB)
if ($matching.Success) {
    while ($matching.Success) {
        "Match found: {0}" -f $matching.Value
        exit $xmlData.Feature.ExitCode.Found
        $matching = $matching.NextMatch()
    }
} else {
    "Not Found" 
    exit $xmlData.Feature.ExitCode.NotFound
}
```

Edit: update for better XML handling, which can handle XML file encodings correctly. Thanks to @tomalak's comments.

Comment: Don't parse XML by casting the result of `Get-Content` to `[xml]`. This is fundamentally wrong. `Get-Content` has no idea what byte encoding the XML file is in and will happily and silently (!) mangle your data. Always use the XML parser to read the file: `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load($path);` because encoding detection is a basic feature of XML parsers.

Comment: @Tomalak is that any different from any other file reading? Get-Content will do some encoding detection, and only the case where PSv5.1 or below reads a UTF8 file without BOM will  you need `-Encoding UTF8`, and that's the default on PSv6+. That [xml reading apparently defaults to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623317/478656) seems useful to save one parameter on get-content, but not by itself "fundamentally" enough to say "never use the convenient type accelerator"

Comment: Yes, it is different. If there is a BOM then Get-Content will catch it. Realistically though, the BOM is only ever mandatory with UTF-16 and UTF-32, and those are rather rare encodings for XML files. For UTF-8, the BOM is optional and actively discouraged. Especially if the file was not created on Windows or downloaded from a webserver, it will be missing. And `Get-Content` does not default to UTF-8. It defaults to *whatever* encoding is configured to be the default on the machine running the script. So `Get-Content` *will* definitely destroy UTF-8 files that have no BOM.

Comment: The XML parser on the other hand will look at - among other things - the XML declaration (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>` and will do the right thing (`Get-Content` OTOH will also silently destroy `Windows-1251` files when it assumes `Windows-1252` as its default.) To get around this with `Get-Content`, you would need to remember to hard-code the file encoding in your script, which will of course fall apart as soon as the XML encoding changes. When you use the XML parser to read the file, you get full flexibility for free.

Comment: @Tomalak the default for Get-Content is ASCII on PSv5.1 and below, and UTF8NoBOM on PSv6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6 ; where did you see that it uses "whatever is default on the machine"? (What even is a "default encoding for a machine"?).  If the XML parser can shift encodings mid-stream, that is a good reason to prefer the XML parser, but also a nightmarish horror of XML design.

Comment: To the contrary: File encoding detection is a very tricky problem, which XML parsers solve very elegantly - the XML declaration is guaranteed to readable in any encoding, and then yes, it will switch encodings mid-stream. It's as close to perfect in an imperfect world as it gets. In fact, it's always a lingering bug to use `Get-Content` without the `-Encoding` parameter, and it should throw a big fat warning IMHO.

Comment: And the "default encoding" is a necessary evil because people hate to choose encodings whenever they read or write files, so one must be chosen for them. On Windows running in Western European locales, the default encoding is `Windows-1252`. Files you create and consume on the same machine are likely to "just work" because of that. The problem begins when files are exchanged between computers. And in case of XML, it's a solved problem that is easily avoided. (End of rant, but this really is a pet peeve of mine. So many people do the wrong thing in good faith)

Comment: @tomalak "*File encoding detection is a very tricky problem*" - it's a stupid problem. "UTF8 has a BOM but it's optional and discouraged" - everything since ~1996 would have been *trivial* if the BOM was, instead, mandatory. That XML has a place to declare an encoding as all files ought to have, is neat, but it isn't a solved problem. "*I don't trust you to use encodings properly when reading a file .. so I'll solve that by moving the problem, and instead trusting you to have used encodings properly when creating the file". Which, people won't do either. But, eh. What other choice is there.

Comment: It's a real-world problem, and sadly one that most people ignore. Sure, if everybody would use UTF-8 we'd be golden, the reality is that's not the case, so it needs to be worked around. When people use XML serializers to write XML files (*as they should!*) then this is a solved problem. XML is a data exchange tool, designed to be created by machines and consumed by machines. Part of the contract is built-in encoding detection. When the file is in a different encoding than the XML declaration says then somebody has fumbled it (i.e. not used an XML serializer) & it's their fault.

Comment: @Tomalak you can't go back in time and declare that EBCDIC and ASCII and Windows-1252 must have BOMs, but when creating UTF16 they made one and made it mandatory, and then UTF8 they made one .. and then perpetuated the encoding problem for eternity instead of fixing it, by making it optional. "*only the party creating the file can know for sure what encoding they are using*" 
 - ideally yes, actually no. Will the "text.xml" file at the end of these bodges https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230 be fitting that description, the creating party being certain of the encoding and its validity?

Comment: Please take this discussion to chat. The comments to an answer are hardly the right place for it.